# error printing element values of map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
map<char, int> counter;

//some code...

map<char, int>::iterator iter;

for (i = 0; i<26; i++) 
    {
    for (iter = counter[i].begin(); iter != counter[i].end(); iter++)  //error occurs
         {
         cout << (*iter).first << " - " << (*iter).second << endl;
         }

    }
```

I'm not sure what this error message means:
*error: request for member âbeginâ in âcounter.std::map<_Key, _Tp , _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = char, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator >, std::map<_Key, __Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = char]((* &((std::map::key_type)j)))â, which is of non-class* *type âstd::map::mapped_type {aka int}â*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

counter is a map not an array of map, one for loop from begin() to end() is enough, change your for loop to below code.

```
    map<char, int> counter;

   //some code...

    for (map<char, int>::iterator iter = counter.begin(); iter != counter[i].end(); ++iter)
    {
       cout << (*iter).first << " - " << (*iter).second << endl;
    }
```

Comment: No, you're right I think I'm getting confused making the switch from arrays. So that part works.. thanks! But, actually yes my map has 26 elements and I'm trying to retrieve an int for each char.